# Rails - ActiveRecord includes for multiple levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

See associations below:

```
class Continent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :countrys

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :continent
    has_many :addresses

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :street

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
```

How can I start with `Person.includes()` and include associations all the way up to the continent when querying the db.

I've been able to include up to the country via `.includes(addresses: :country)`, however it seems not to get the last level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add 1 more level of hash:

> .includes(addresses: {country: :continent})

Comment: Should it not be `.includes(addresses: {countries: :continents})`?